# Browsers doesn't clean history on exit

Tags: firefox, browser, budgie, 21.04, brave

I’m new to GNU/Linux and Ubuntu. I’m currently running Ubuntu Budgie 21.04. I have problems with browsers. Normally I use brave and clear data on exit doesn't clear history and other stuff on exit. I tried to open via terminal and results are:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
Opening in existing browser session.
```

After that, I tried Firefox and  clear data on exit doesn't clear history and other stuff on exit, neither. But there is no terminal error.

After that I tried Ephemeral. It doesn’t open. Terminal errors are:

```
Gtk-Message: 22:09:48.800: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
Gtk-Message: 22:09:48.801: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

(com.github.cassidyjames.ephemeral:46215): dbind-WARNING **: 22:09:48.853: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-BzY1JqIs3l: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: 22:09:48.938: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 22:09:48.946: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

After all that, I tried to clean history end of the day. I doesn't clean.

And other problem is that I can't install extensions on Brave.

I removed browsers and installed again. Still the same.

My computer is Asus ROG Strix G531GT-BQ002T Intel Core i5 9300H 8GB 512GB SSD GTX1650.

Comment: You might want to address this to Brave Support directly >>> https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us

Comment: I don't think it is only about Brave since firefox has same problem.